# Angular 2 - What module bundle am I using

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

I am building a web app using angular cli with ng new command. However, I have came across a few post talking about if I am using webpack I should do this or if I am using systemJs I should do this... However I do not know which one I am using? Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.18",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.6.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.6.6",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "ng2-date-time-picker": "^1.0.7",
    "ng2-datetime": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-datetime-picker": "^0.12.7",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.39",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

[image: folder structure]

Comment: Angular switches from systemjs to webpack altogether awhile ago

Answer (score 0):

Angular CLI uses the Webpack build system.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#webpack-update